# SAML Response is empty - GetExternalLoginInfoAsync is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, okta, kentor-authservices

I am using Okta as an identity provider and configured the metadata, url, etc in startup. The request is going to Okta server and after entering username 
and password validate the user and response comes back. But when check in 
fiddler the response is blank. SAMLResponse is blank. The relaystate there is a 
hashed long string. Hence my GetExternalLoginInfoAsync is null. Any idea on this 
issue. Also setup the firstName, LastName etc in Okta.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue would be better addressed if you email us directly, as you'll need to provide additional details regarding what your SAML request consists of, and what the response looks like. Please email developers@okta.com.

Comment: Hi Shradha, Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi Shradha, Thanks for the response. Just now I emailed to developers@okta.com. Please can you take this as an urgent. Awaiting your response. Let me know for any more information required.

Comment: Hi Shradha, I send email with all the trace files to Sohaib. Please can you get back to me on this.

Comment: Hi VVR, Sohaib is looking into this. Thanks for your patience!